# Visualizing just top portion of stacked barplot in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I made a stacked barplot in ggplot2 in R:

```
ggplot(Count_dataframe_melt, aes(x = as.factor(variable), y = value, fill = fill)) + 
 geom_bar(stat = "identity",position="fill")+ scale_y_continuous(name = "Y-axis",labels = scales::percent)
```

[image: Current visualization in ggplot2]

I want to just visualize the top portion of the stacked barplot like so:

[image: Visualization that I want]

I've looked everywhere and can't figure out how to do this. Does anyone know how?

Comment: See `?ggplot2::coord_cartesian`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coord_cartesian` to "zoom in" on the area you want.

```
# your plot code...
ggplot(Count_dataframe_melt, aes(x = as.factor(variable), y = value, fill = fill)) + 
 geom_bar(stat = "identity",position="fill") + 
 scale_y_continuous(name = "Y-axis",labels = scales::percent) +
 # set axis limits in coord_cartesian
 coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.75, 1))
```

Note that many people consider bar plots that *don't* start at 0 misleading. A line plot may be a better way to visualize this data.

Answer (score 0):

Since the areas you want to show are less than 20% of the total area, you could flip the bar charts so that you only show the colors areas. Then the y-axis goes from 0-25% and you can use the figure caption to describe that the remaining data is in the gray category.